# Change namespace in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces

I have namespaced routing like

> /example/list/

```
namespace :example do
  resource :list
  ...
end
```

Need to change it to

> /newexample/list/

I can certainly do it by changing example => newexample in routes.rb, but  module **example** is used vastly in the project. so changing it by this method would require to update almost each Controller, Js, CSS file.

Is there any way to map newexample => example namespace in routes.rb? or Any other out of box solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify a path when using a namespace with the `path` option. In your example you would have something like this:

```
namespace :example, path: 'newexample' do
  resources :list
end
```

You can also specify the module instead, like so

```
namespace :newexample, module: :example do
  resources :list
end
```

The routes created will be the same (`/newexample/list` will map to the `example` module).

The difference will be in the route helper names: for the first example, your helper will be `example_lists_path`, in the second one it will look like `newexample_lists_path` (which means you would have to update your links in your views)

You can also check the [docs on scoping routes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html) if you need more detailed info